# ZERO_RESULTS shows when trying to get latitude and longitude using google map API

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3

I have use the given code to get the longitude and latitude of a place.

```
function get_coordinates($city, $street, $province)
{
  $address = urlencode($city.','.$street.','.$province);
  $url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&sensor=false&region=Poland&key=******";
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
 $response = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 $response_a = json_decode($response);
 $status = $response_a->status;
 if ( $status == 'ZERO_RESULTS' )
{
   return FALSE;
}
else
{
  $return = array('lat' => $response_a->results[0]->geometry->location->lat, 'long' => $long = $response_a->results[0]->geometry->location->lng);
return $return;
}
```

This work for some places and for some place it shows ZERO_RESULTS. I am getting the place from google place using google API. 
Example: Dubai Silicon Oasis - Dubai - United Arab Emirates(not working).
I am calling this function as get_coordinates($from, $from, 'Śląskie');
where $from=Dubai Silicon Oasis - Dubai - United Arab Emirates
Anything wrong with this? If so how can I get the city,street and province from the place I have? Anything wrong with the url? I am using this code for an application to use it in UAE. Do I need to change the region in url?

I have checked the $address and it seems wrong. For Dubai Silicon Oasis - Dubai - United Arab Emirates $address shows %2C%2C%C5%9Al%C4%85skie. and for The Dubai Mall - Dubai - United Arab Emirates $address is The+Dubai+Mall+-+Dubai+-+United+Arab+Emirates%2CThe+Dubai+Mall+-+Dubai+-+United+Arab+Emirates%2C%C5%9Al%C4%85skie(correct). Why this happen so? anybody please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the latitude and longitude of a "place" (like "Dubai Silicon Oasis - Dubai - United Arab Emirates", which is not a postal address) use the Places API.

See the [geocoding "best practices" page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/best-practices) for more details.

From that link:

> Ambiguous queries in an automated system (for example, incomplete or poorly formatted addresses)

use:

> Places API Text Search service to obtain place IDs, then the Geocoding API to geocode the place IDs into latlngs.

Comment: I can't understand. Please be much more clear. I am just a beginner in using google API. I am using google map API to get place and that place is using to get the longitude and latitude for getting distance between two places.

Comment: that place is there in google map as such. but here it is detecting correctly in address

Comment: As mentioned by geocodezip: Geocoding API (http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json...) should not be used for finding the location of a business listing. Geocoding API is designed to tell you the latlng of a given formatted address (ie. Some Street 5, SomeCity, SomeCountry) but not of a business/POI (ie. Some Business, SomeCity, SomeCountry). To get a location of a business/POI you should use Places API to get the business address ( https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Some+Business,SomCity,SomeCountry)  from there you will get a formatted_address and location.